# Stopping Race Conditions by Adding Race Conditions?

Tags: file, permissions, c

I'm doing a theoretical exercise for a class. We are given this snippit of UNIX C code which is vulnerable to race conditions between the access() call and the open() call.

```
/*  vulp.c  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define DELAY 10000

int main()
{
   char * fn = "/tmp/XYZ";
   char buffer[60];
   FILE *fp;
   long int  i;

   /* get user input */
   scanf("%50s", buffer );

   if(!access(fn, W_OK)){
       /* simulating delay */
        for (i=0; i < DELAY; i++){
           int a = i^2; 
        }

        fp = fopen(fn, "a+");
        fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, fp);
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fp);
        fclose(fp);
   }
   else printf("No permission \n");
}
```

If an attacker were to point to a file they did not own and win the race condition, they could overwrite a file without permission. It seems like this can be fixed by adding more access() and open() calls so that there are so many race conditions its virtually impossible to win them all. I figured adding a for loop around the current access and open call would do that but wouldn't that just mean the attacker only has to win the last race condition? If so how can I repeat the access and open calls in a way that preserves the functionality of the program and makes a bad race condition a statistical improbability?

Comment: This probably should be asked on [security.se], though I have a feeling they'd prefer [so].

Comment: The attacker would regardless only have to win the last gap between the  access/fopen calls, and the naive brute force attack of spamming symlink/unlink calls would not be influenced by the added complexity of some sort of for loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about programming and security. It would be better off on [security.se], though [so] would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when implementing security solutions, it is considered dangerous to reinvent the wheel. This is particular true for cryptographic operations, but this is another example. You really want to understand all the ins and outs of attackers methods before you attempt to defeat them.

For example, on the OWASP website ([here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_Access_Race_Condition:_TOCTOU)) it mentions that attackers have techniques to increase the size of the timing window - so you should understand those techniques among others.

Short of that kind of thorough understanding, go with a well vetted solution, such as the one described [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO45-C.+Avoid+TOCTOU+race+conditions+while+accessing+files) which uses the 'wx' flag to `fopen()`